# ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyCObject_Type

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

This is how I installed opencv3 on my machine.
I had python 3.6 installed in my system. I ran,

```
$ brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --with-python3 --HEAD
```

Then changed the name of opencv3 package in the 3.6 site package.

```
$ cd /usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
$ mv cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so cv2.so
```

And then created .pth file.

```
$ echo /usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages >> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/opencv3.pth
```

Now when I get on the python 3 REPL and call

```
import cv2
```

This is the error that I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyCObject_Type
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
```

I want my python 3 interpreter to look into the python 3.6 site packages for cv2 and I can't get it to do that. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I would reinstall opencv from source using CMake.

Comment: I would like to believe there's a simpler way to make the python3 interpreter look into the 3.6 site packages.

Comment: It looks like `brew` install opencv for python3.5 while you want to use python3.6. I'm not sure there's a way to overcome that, unless you tweak the formula. On the other note, why did the erros mention python2.7?

Comment: I had the same problem some time ago. I resolved it installing opencv-python. (pip install opencv-python) . It does all the binding for you.

Answer (score 0):

I removed all opencv3 folders and removed the opencv package in python environment and then installed opencv again. It's working for me now.